# JS when user click show different colors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When you enter the page, the first `div` `#faqBasics`, should be in a different color.
If the user click in one of the other two div's, that should be in different color, where the other's muts be in the original color.

If the user click in some question, that question should be in a different color. But if he clicks in other questions, the first one should be with the original color.

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/S5VQ8/)

HTML:

```
<div id="faqBasics">BASICS</div> | <div id="faqNetworking">NETWORKING</div> | <div id="faqCompression">COMPRESSION</div>
        <br /><br />
        <div class="faqBasics">
            <ul>
                <li>Question?</li>
                    <div class="basicsAnswers">
                        text
                        <br /><br />
                    </div>
                <li>Question?</li>
                    <div class="basicsAnswers">
                        text
                        <br /><br />
                    </div>
                <li>Question?</li>
                    <div class="basicsAnswers">
                        text
                    </div>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="faqNetworking">
            <ul>
                <li>Question?</li>
                    <div class="networkingAnswers">
                        text
                        <br /><br />
                    </div>
                <li>Question?</li>
                    <div class="networkingAnswers"> 
                        text
                        <br /><br />
                    </div>
                <li>Question?</li>
                    <div class="networkingAnswers">
                        text
                    </div>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="faqCompression">
            <ul>
                <li>Question?</li>
                    <div class="compressionAnswers">
                        text
                        <br /><br />
                    </div>
                <li>Question?</li>
                    <div class="compressionAnswers">
                        text 
                        <br /><br />
                    </div>
                <li>Question?</li>
                    <div class="compressionAnswers">
                        text
                        <br /><br />
                    </div>
                <li>Question?</li>
                    <div class="compressionAnswers">
                        text
                    </div>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
#faqBasics, #faqNetworking, #faqCompression {
display:inline;
cursor: pointer;
}

li {
list-style: none;
overflow: hidden;
cursor: pointer;
color:#c8c8c8;
margin-bottom: 15px;
}

li.active {
color: #c8c8c8;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('li').each(function() {
    var tis = $(this), state = false, answer = tis.next('.basicsAnswers, .networkingAnswers, .compressionAnswers').hide().css('height','auto').slideUp();
    tis.click(function() {
        state = !state;
        $('.basicsAnswers, .networkingAnswers, .compressionAnswers').hide();
        $(this).css("color", "#6001ff");
        answer.slideToggle(state);
        tis.toggleClass('active',state);
    });
}
);
$(".faqBasics").show();
$(".faqNetworking,.faqCompression").hide();
$("#faqBasics,#faqNetworking,#faqCompression").click(function(){
    $(this).css("color", "#6001ff");
    $(".faqBasics,.faqNetworking,.faqCompression").hide();
    $("div."+$(this).attr("id")).show();
});
});
```

Any ideas what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/kermani/S5VQ8/1/)

you forgot to remove blue color from all `li`

```
 $('li').css('color','black');
```

Comment: Ahhh! Okay! That's it. Can you update that fiddle, for the first's div when the user click just one stay with the color? I mean: <div id="faqBasics">BASICS</div> | <div id="faqNetworking">NETWORKING</div> | <div id="faqCompression">COMPRESSION</div>